Автоматизация копирования информации из одной программы в ворд
Такой вопрос. Необходимо, каким-то образом автоматизировать процесс. На своей работе, я рутинно каждый день исполняю определённый ряд процессов, связанный с копированием информации из ячеек (инпутов) статистической программы и переводом этой информации в соответствующие экспресс блоки ворда. Я хочу, чтобы скрипт/макрос/программа брал информацию из соответсвующей ячейки в стат. программе и переносил ее в соответствующую ячейку в ворде. Подскажите пожалуйста, какие есть возможности или варианты решения вопроса? Какие есть возможности автоматизации процесса? Спасибо миряне

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

не очень ясно что вы делаете и зачем, но если вам надо чтобы что то кликало мышкой и кнопки нажимало, есть такой инструмент autohotkey. Но вообще если вы переводите данные из одной программы в другую, то может быть поискать вариант какого то экпорта данных / отчетности..
